# Bash string (command output) equality test

Tags: bash

I have a simple script to check whether webpage contains a specified string. It looks like:

```
#!/bin/bash
res=`curl -s "http://www.google.com" | grep "foo bar foo bar" | wc -l`
if [[ $res == "0" ]]; then
    echo "OK"
else
    echo "Wrong"
fi
```

As you can see, I am looking to get "OK", but got a "Wrong".

What's wrong with it?

If I use if [ $res == "0" ], it works. If I just use res="0" instead of res=`curl...`, it also can obtain the desired results.

Why are there these differences?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer in [glenn jackman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7552/glenn-jackman)'s help.

I get the following points in this question:

- `wc -l` 's output contains whitespaces.
- Debugging with `echo "$var"` instead of `echo $var`
- `[[` preserves the literal value of all characters within the var.
- `[` expands var to their values before perform, it's because [ is actually the `test` cmd, so it follows [Shell Expansions](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Expansions.html#Shell-Expansions) rules.

Answer (score 24):

You could see what `res` contains: `echo "Wrong: res=>$res<"`

If you want to see if some text contains some other text, you don't have to look at the *length* of grep output: you should look at grep's return code:

```
string="foo bar foo bar"
if curl -s "http://www.google.com" | grep -q "$string"; then
    echo "'$string' found"
else
    echo "'$string' not found"
fi
```

Or even without grep:

```
text=$(curl -s "$url")
string="foo bar foo bar"
if [[ $text == *"$string"* ]]; then
    echo "'$string' found"
else
    echo "'$string' not found in text:"
    echo "$text"
fi
```

Comment: Thanks, it's good solution. But, as my question, I just want know why [[ $res == "0" ]] isn't work in this case, so that I can avoid making the same mistakes in the future

Comment: what do you see with `od -c <<< "$res"`? Are there extra whitespace characters?

Comment: Yes, you are right, there are whitespaces in wc output. Thanks.